# re.search no lee todas las coincidences

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Estoy haciendo una expresión regular para encontrar todas las palabras de una frase. Tengo lo siguiente:

```
import re

emoji_pattern = re.compile('[A-Za-z]+')


print(emoji_pattern.search("jajaja que haces?"))
```

Pero al momento de correrlo me da

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 6), match='jajaja'>
```

que sólo dice que la palabra `jajaja`.

Es la única que encuentra, mas sin embargo debería de dar todas las palabras.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una opción sencilla es usar [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), como [describió @TheSupermax03](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/144060/127).

Una opción más eficiente es usar [re.finditer()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer), que genera un iterador, especialmente si se trata de un texto largo.

```
import re

regex = r"[A-Za-z]+"
texto = "jajaja que haces?"

for match in re.finditer(regex, texto):
    print( match.group(0) )
```

```
jajaja
que
haces
```

Además, [re.finditer()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) permite obtener el texto capturado por cada grupo, en cada coincidencia.

<sup>* y funciona bien con coincidencias vacías, donde `findall` se saltea 1 caracter.</sup>

Comment: Muchas gracias, de echo estuve probando porque estoy tratando de encontrar emojis en una cadena de texto pero con `re.findall()` no me encontraba la cadena de texto sólo los emojis pero con `re.finditer()` me mostró los emojis junto con el texto.

Comment: Me alegro de que te ayudara @LuisMiguel. Ese comportamiento es a lo que me refería con "*cada grupo*", porque cuando se usan paréntesis, `findall` devuelve sólo lo que coincidió con los paréntesis, que sería lo mismo que lo que devuelve `match.group(1)` con `finditer`... Por estos motivos, siempre recomiendo usar `finditer` a menos que se esté completamente seguro de que se prefiere el resultado que da `findall`.

Answer (score 3):

Lo que sucede es que search te devuelve el primer match que encuentre de acuerdo a la expresión regular que usaste, por eso en tu caso devolvió `jajaja`. Si queres que encuentre todas las ocurrencias podés usar findall. Tu código con findall quedaría de la siguiente manera

```
import re

emoji_pattern = re.compile('[A-Za-z]+')
print(emoji_pattern.findall('jajaja que haces?'))
```

La salida es la siguiente:

```
  ['jajaja', 'que', 'haces']
```

Incluyo algunos links para visitar:

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.search
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#re.findall

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me funciono.